# Understanding SSL Certificate Types

Tags: security, ssl, asp.net-web-api, https, ssl-certificate

I'm building my first web app and I have two questions about security.

1. I'll send and receive very sensitive data with `POST` request to my
   api which will be hosted on Azure or AWS. Can I send and receive
   data in plaintext over SSL, is it secure? I can access my
   azure web site over `https`, is it secure enough or should I buy another
   SSL sertificate?
2. I've searched a little bit and there are different types of SSL
   certificates, I read some certificates provide green padlock or green address bar but I don't need these kinds of things since my web app only
   will be available to my mobile app and there will be no content to browse. Only one page with download links to my mobile app in case someone finds this site. So all certificates are secure on same level for my situation?

P.S. I won't add custom domain name, if that's relevant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Answering your questions one at a time;

1. Modern implementations of SSL are generally considered to be pretty
   rock-solid; its used by banks, healthcare institutions, and major
   internet companies. Sending data in plaintext, over SSL, is
   safe enough for those applications, and trying to replace SSL with
   your own encryption scheme is almost certainly more trouble than its worth.
   You should probably get your own SSL certificate; I don't know what restrictions Azure has on https access, if any, and its always bad practice to rely on a key you cannot control.
2. SSL relies on networks of trust; browsers (and other internet applications) validate the certificates sites send them against a
   set of trusted authorities. If the certificate has been approved
   (signed with the authority's private key), the browser accepts the
   certificate as genuine and uses it to negotiate an SSL connection
   with the site without further complaint. This is what that green
   padlock/address bar means; that a site has provided a valid
   certificate signed by an authority the browser trusts. This doesn't
   mean that a signed certificate is inherently more secure than an
   unsigned certificate, however. Both use the same cryptographic
   algorithms, and (can) have the same length keys, and the SSL
   connections each can set up are equally secure. The difference
   between the two is that you can't verify the "authenticity" of an
   unsigned/self-signed certificate; an attacker could intercept the
   connection and replace an unsigned certificate with their own
   certificate, and the browser would have no way of telling if it got
   the right certificate or not. You can overcome this problem in your
   application, however, with a technique called "[certificate
   pinning](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Certificate_and_Public_Key_Pinning)".
   Essentially, you package the public key for your certificate with
   your application, and your application only accepts the certificate
   associated with that key when setting up a connection.

Ultimately, it depends on your attacker model. Are you protecting this data from criminals and casual wiretappers? Or are you trying to hide it from government surveillance and intelligence agencies? For the former, an SSL certificate signed and issued by a reputable authority is more than sufficient. For the latter, you have to consider where your certificate is coming from, and who can access the root CA that issued it; it might be better to generate your own, and devise some further scheme on top of SSL.

Comment: The last part about "generate your own" certificate makes an assumption that the OPs website is secure.

Comment: If his website is compromised enough that an attacker could affect the generation of an SSL certificate, then said attacker would certainly be able to steal any certificate OP purchased. Otherwise, I'm not certain what you mean?

Comment: Agree. If the server is not more secure than a CA why generate your own cert? For CAs that are recognized by the OS/browser the CA protection is better than an above average user site.

Comment: Agreed, which is why I only advised generating your own cert if you are defending against a government, i.e. are paranoid enough that you might not want to trust the CA. If, for example, the NSA had access to the Verisign root certs, a Verisign-provided certificate could be compromised, while a self-generated certificate in a secure environment could not.